# how to append a counter of the number of pattern matches at the end of the line?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I am trying to append a counter of the pattern matches at the end of the line.

sample input:

```
>first_match
a
b
>second_match
c
d
```

wanted output:

```
>first_match,1
a
b
>second_match,2
c
d
```

what I did was this but I don't know how to add the counter:

```
sed '/>.*$/ s/$/,/' file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I notice that you've tagged this [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), but only show examples in `sed`.

Awk is a different tool with different strengths and limitations. In particular `awk` has a more general concept of variable then `sed` does and this becomes very easy.

Try:

```
awk '/^>/{printf("%s,%d\n",$0,++counter);next}{print $0}' file
```

A more 'awkward' solution would be simply:

```
awk '/^>/ { $0=$0 "," ++i }1' file
```

both of which take advantage of the default value for uninitialized variables.

Comment: @dmckee can you please explain what he wanted and what you solved. i am not able to find what was his question and what you solved. is that one file or that was command prompt. i didn't get that

Comment: @user19340357 The code above is to be entered verbatim at the unix command prompt (either a borne shell or csh derivative should do fine). They count the number of lines starting with a `>` character and output those line with an appended comma and the current count. All other lines are printed unmodified. My version should be pretty cleay as it is naive, steve's version is compact and clever and relies on the default action for matches (which is print the line) and the fact that `1` which evaluates to logical true matches all lines.